# in eclipse why there's limit in call hierarchy?

Tags: java, eclipse

I tried to explore callee tree but got a stop error

[image: picture about the limit in call hierarchy in eclipse]

Comment: That image does not show any error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

nvm, I got it.

Step 1:

[image]

Step 2:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[According to the documentation](http://eclipse-tools.sourceforge.net/call-hierarchy/usage.html):

> There are two preference pages (Java/Call Hierarchy) and (Java/Call Hierarchy/Filters). Here it is possible to set up:
>
> - The maximum call depth shown (useful if you want to avoid Eclipse to run forever if you press the * key on the numeric keyboard).

Perhaps you have a limit set there?

Comment: there's no Java/Call Hierarchy page in preferences

Comment: Last published: 19 June 2003 | Doc for 0.5.1

Comment: The maximum depth can now be set from the _Call Hierarchy_ view's menu (click on the three dots on the top right corner > Filters...)